# No more than 1024 pending put on a single channel

Tags: clojurescript, core.async

I'm not too familiar with core.async, but from what I've read, I know I can do stuff like this:

```
;; fetch data
(defn get-data-from-server
  []
  (let [ch (chan)]
    (fetch-data-from-server (fn [result]
                              (put! ch result)))
    ch))

;; echo data
(go-loop []
  (let [v (<! (get-data-from-server))]
    (.log js/console v)))
```

Assume I need to get fresh data from server for every 1000ms, this is what I did:

```
(defn get-data-from-server
  []
  (let [ch (chan)]
    (.setInterval js/window
                  (fetch-data-from-server (fn [result]
                                            (put! ch result))) 1000)
    ch))
```

After some time it complains something like `No more than 1024 pending put on a single channel, consider using ....`. Any suggestion?

Comment: have had a similar problem; hope someone can assist. How many puts would you say are going onto your channel every second?

Comment: @hellofunk because I'm only executing that code, it should be 1 `put!` per second.

Comment: I find that a bit surprising; the problem I'm having occurs with a very large amount of puts!, rapidly. I can't understand how 1 put per second could cause the issue you see unless they are not getting taken immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating a brand new channel every time your go-loop runs? Perhaps you should not create the channel inside the go loop and only reference an already-created channel. That tends to be much more common and better performant.

Comment: @FarisNasution I should add that you are also not closing these newly created channels, which you should always do even if you want to create a new channel every time for some reason. Please comment again here if you continue to see the same pending puts error.